# How can I force the function documentation popup to show when editing an invocation in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tooltip

When typing a function invocation in VS Code, it shows a useful popup which documents the function, and each parameter as I add its argument. But this popup only seems to be triggered when editing the function name part of the invocation. If I move the cursor somewhere else, closing the popup, when I go back to editing the invocation arguments, I can't get the same popup back unless I edit the name again. How can I open this popup without going back to the function name?

Comment: You can try to hover the mouse pointer over the function name.

Comment: That one disappears when I start editing the parameters. I can only get the one I want by editing the function name, selecting one of the completion suggestions, then adding fresh arguments. The popup then stays on screen and updates as I add each argument, highlighting the one I'm working on. If there are arguments already present and I try to edit them, the popup disappears.